# How to remove p tags around img tags Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have images like

```
<p>
<img alt="" src="http://some_dummy_image.JPG" style="width: 263px; height: 306.77px;"/>
</p>
```

What I do :

```
for x in soup.find_all("p"):
    if (len(x.get_text(strip=True)) == 0):
        img = x.findChildren("img")
            if len(img):
                 x.replaceWith(img[0])
```

I would just like to get rid of

tags wrapping around the img tag.

Answer (score 0):

[`tag.unwrap()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) should do the trick. Only added the prints so you can see the difference.

```
print(soup) # this is your initial structure

for x in soup.find_all("p"):
    x.unwrap()

print(soup) # this is the structure without p tag
```